# Why does the "rebase and merge" option in Github create new commit SHAs? Is there an alternative?

Tags: github

I like using the "rebase and merge" option for merging PRs in Github to avoid cluttering the commit history with merge commits.

But I've noticed the following behavior:
(from Github's [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-merge-methods-on-github/#rebasing-and-merging-your-commits))

> The rebase and merge behavior on GitHub deviates slightly from git rebase. Rebase and merge on GitHub will always update the committer information and create new commit SHAs, whereas git rebase outside of GitHub does not change the committer information when the rebase happens on top of an ancestor commit.

This seems strange to me since it's not how rebase works from the git CLI. Does anyone know why it behaves this way?

Ideally, I'd like to both a) avoid introducing merge commits and b) preserve the commit SHAs and tags from the feature branch. Is there a way to do this from the UI?

Comment: I just want to point out that even if GitHub didn't force rewriting the commits like the CLI, your desire to preserve the commit IDs would only work sometimes (when the branch is already up to date). This is what AzureDevOps does with rebase strategies; it *might* rewrite the commits when it's rebased, and you find out if it did after the PR is completed. If nothing else, at least GitHub is consistent and you *know* commits will be re-written. 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I'd like to both
>
> a) avoid introducing merge commits

You won't have any merge commit created, since the doc mentions:

> all commits from the topic branch (or head branch) are added onto the base branch individually **without a merge commit**.
> Pull requests with rebased commits are merged using the **[fast-forward option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge)**.

And:

> b) preserve the commit SHAs and tags from the feature branch.

Any rebase (locally or remotely on GitHub) would change the SHA1 anyway (since a rebase, by definition, changes the base parent commit).
As [Mondkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979505/mondkin) helpfully [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350294/why-does-the-rebase-and-merge-option-in-github-create-new-commit-shas-is-ther/48353418#comment83693450_48353418), a rebase made on top of an *ancestor* commit leaves the commits alone.
If GitHub still does change the SHA1, that means some other metadata (date, or comment) is changed for GitHub to reflect/record that operation, and make sure it is visible (as opposed to a local repo, where a rebase on top of a local ancestor is a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP): nothing happens).

Comment: Not every rebase changes the hash: a rebase made on top of an ancestor commit leaves the commits alone. That is actually what is mentioned in the quote made by @SamHanes, about the difference in behaviour between GitHub and git CLI (in GitHub even rebases on top of ancestor commits introduce new commits)

Comment: @MondKin Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and expanded on it.

Comment: I think you've hit upon the "why" - the committer metadata is updated on the commits, hence the new SHAs.  I was hoping to preserve the tag placed on the feature branch after merging it, but that doesn't seem possible in this workflow.  Thanks @VonC and @MondKin!

Comment: i was just bitten by the same issue, and i really wonder whether somebody has an idea as to *why* the committer metadata is updated (esp. if it was *me* who committed originally and who did the rebase-and-merge).

Answer (score 9):

Your appreciation is correct, that's not how rebase works in git. The reason is in GitHub some options are poorly named:

- **Squash and Merge**: Is similar to a squash and a **rebase**
- **Rebase and Merge**: Is similar to a rebase with the `--no-ff` option (and even when the commit is up to date, a new commit will be introduced instead)

And if you are using the "GitHub Desktop" application you should have seen other unfamiliar names like "Sync" instead of "Pull"+"Merge"+"Push".

Comment: Aren't "Rebase and Merge" commits were merged with the ff option?

Comment: I don't quite get the question, but a fast-forward implies no new commit is made if one commit is an ancestor of the other.

Comment: You stated that rebase and merge "Is actually a rebase with the --no-ff option" - the documentation I quoted seems to suggest the opposite.

Comment: The documentation is right: `Rebase and Merge` is a rebase where even in fast-forward (and up-to-date) scenarios it will introduce new commits (so it will not fast-forward, which is like saying it uses the `-no-ff` option). I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @SamHanes the confusion here is because, yes, the *merge* is done with ff (meaning no merge commit will be created), but the *rebase* is done with `--no-ff`, meaning it will rewrite the commits even if it didn't need to. Note in the context of `rebase`, `--no-ff` is an alternate option for `--force-rebase` or `-f`. [Documentation here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---no-ff).

Comment: This is annoying as we cannot keep the SSH signature from the original author in GitHub and keep the history clean. The closest solution is with the commit merge because the original commits will be preserved, but an additional merge commit will be added every time, no matter what.

Comment: For security, we should be able to validate the SSH signature in the main branch after a merge. Otherwise, what is the point of forcing signatures if we cannot validate a supply chain attack that goes to production? We could even automate an allowed signature list in the CI/CD process, but that behavior prevents it.